# unable to get response form an API in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-8, guzzle

I am getting null response in laravel after dd(); ,however in Postman i am getting a response, maybe I am passing the wrong body to the API, kindly guide me on how to pass the following body to this API.

Thanks for your help.

This is my controller

```
public function callpdf(Request $req)
  {
    // code...
    $host = new HostClass();
    $obj = new SessionClass();
    $response8 = Http::POST($host->getserverIp() . '/PDFReport',[
      // "patientId"=> $obj->getpatientId(),
      "patientId"=>"001000010818",
      "reportId"=> "618",
      "con"=>"003001200326197",
      "departmentId"=> "128",
      "orderStatusId" => "12",
      "organizationId"=>"332",
      "sessionId"=> "3",
      
    ]);
  
    dd($response8);
    return $response8;
  }
```

This is Postman request and response

```
{
       "patientId": "001000010818",
        "departmentId": "128",
        "con": "003001200326197",
        "odi": "2",
        "orderStatusId" : "12",
        "reportId": "618",
        "organizationId":"332",
        "sessionId": "3"
}
```

Comment: I assume that you checked that the url you are requesting is right : `$host->getserverIp() . '/PDFReport'` ? if you dd this, you have a well formed url like the one you have in postman ?

Comment: @Floxblah yes my URL is correct as I've called other APIs in the way correctly but for this one, I assume I am sending the body in the wrong way.

Comment: I don't know anything about the api you are calling so maybe check that you are sending the good elements in your body. Also, what's type of format your api assume to get in the body ? json ? form-data ?

Comment: @Floxblah it's body elements that causing the problem, yes in JSON format

Comment: Need more clarification

Comment: Is your `callPdf` method a `web` or `api` route? When using Postman, are you calling the API directly?

Comment: @Peppermintology it's a web route, API is "PDFReport"

Comment: You say you get null response in laravel and some result in postman when using `dd()`. This is normal. If you use `callpdf` as a function in php, and use `dd()` you interrupt the flow of code. If you call this function in a route and then use postman to view the result, `dd()` will echo some values to postman. It won't necessarily be properly formatted, but it shows something. Remove your `dd()` and change your return line to `return $response8->getBody()->getContents();` if you want to return the proper response. You could wrap this in a `json_decode()` to get a workable php class or array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am getting null response in laravel after dd();, however in Postman i am getting a response

Based on your response to my question:

> Is your callPdf method a web or api route? When using Postman, are you calling the API directly?

> @Peppermintology it's a web route, API is "PDFReport"

I would expect this behaviour. You're using `dd();` which is Laravels `dump and die` method. What this does is `dump` the data you provide it and then `die` which halts execution meaning nothing after the `dd()` is ever executed.

So your `return` statement is never executed, hence no response.

Answer (score 0):

I see your code. The code looks fine but in my thinking problem could be at multiple parts of the HTTP request.

- First Look at the URL this may be difference between URL or postman and your request. First, verify that
- The second problem may be due to some headers like (Accept, Content-Type) to be application/json.

Comment: This is not a solution, it's speculation about what might be wrong. This belongs in comments ;)